# how to make a page active for dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my view page..by giving like this when i click a page all pages are becoming active

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="Categories filter"> <span class="filter-title">Categories</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>hardpolo_control/men">View All </a></li>
   <?php foreach($mendropdown as $row){?>
    <li class="<?php if($active_mn=='men_image') echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>hardpolo_control/men_image/<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->category_name;?> <span> </span></a></li>
    <?php }?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

my controler looks like this..

```
public function men_image($category_id=null)    
{        
    $data['active_mn']='men_image';
    $data['mendropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);

    $this->load->view('men_image',$data);
}
```

Comment: u can use title passing throug controller to view then check in loop which title is equal to ur link

Comment: i had given like that but still its not working

Comment: i had changed my code please see

Comment: no its not worked u start php tag inside php old one is better

Comment: yaa..any other way

Comment: i edited ur question and now change this line <?php if($active_mn=='men_image') echo 'active'; ?> to 
<?php echo ($active_mn=='men_image') ? 'active' : "" ; ?>

Comment: i changed..but still in the same way

Comment: just to test change this echo ($active_mn=='men_image') ? 'active' : "" ; ?>
to
echo (1==1) ? 'active' : "" ; ?>

Comment: check in your console i am sure active is now added cause 1 is always = to 1

Comment: console doesnt show any error

Comment: yup not error .. but li have class active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are checking equality with your given value ('men_image'), It will be same for all iteration. Instead you need to compare with $row value.

Try this

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="Categories filter"> <span class="filter-title">Categories</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>hardpolo_control/men">View All </a></li>
   <?php foreach($mendropdown as $row){?>
    <li class="<?php if($active_mn== $row->id) echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>hardpolo_control/men_image/<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->category_name;?> <span> </span></a></li>
    <?php }?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
 public function men_image($category_id=null)    
    {        
        $data['active_mn']= $category_id;
        $data['mendropdown']=$this->Hardpolo_model->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);

        $this->load->view('men_image',$data);
    }
```

Comment: yaa..what u said is correct..there iam having doubt

Comment: do you have 'men_image' value in your table?

Comment: the category_name is there in my table

Comment: yaa sure its helps me a lot